# Data Structures to represent logical expressions

Tags: python, data-structures, logic-programming

Here is a logical statement:

```
term1 AND (term2 OR term3) OR term4
```

What is an effective way of storing this information in a data structure?

For example, should I use a graph, with a property on each edge defining the operator to the next term? (This suggestion doesn't make sense IMO, but it's a data structure that might be useful for this)

Answer (score 9):

I used an object graph to code something similar before. Each object in the graph has its own structure.

For example:

```
BinaryLogicalExpression : BooleanExpression
{
  Left : BooleanExpression
  Right : BooleanExpression
  Operator : BinaryLogicalOperator
}
ArithmeticExpression : Expression
{
  Left : Expression
  Right : Expression
  Operator : ArithmeticOperator
}
// for modelling brackets...
LogicalGroupExpression : BooleanExpression
{
  GroupedExpression : BooleanExpression
}
// to hold constant values...
IntegerConstant : Expression
{
  Value : int
}
StringConstant : Expression
{
  Value : string
}
```

I'd then use a series of `Visitor` implementations to traverse the object graph for  evaluation and processing of the expression.

```
Expression
{
  Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor);
}

ExpressionVisitor
{
  Visit(BinaryLogicalExpression e);
  Visit(ArithmeticExpression e);
  Visit(StringConstant e);
  Visit(IntegerConstant e);
  etc...
}
```

Using an object graph and `Visitor` makes it easy to serialize such expressions to XML or similar hierarchical data structure.

Answer (score 2):

an array could be used, so:

```
term1 AND ( (term2 OR term3) OR term4 )
```

would be:

```
[ {term1}, 
  { 'OR' : [ { 'OR' : [ {term2} , {term3} ] },
             {term4}
           ]
  }

]
```

in PHP:

```
array('term1',array('OR'=>array(array('OR'=>array('term2','term3')),'term4')));
```

this notation is used in the CakePhp framework =).

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I'd try trees, nest them so that each level has the operator on a left branch and all the data on a right branch ala Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

In C you might do something like this:

```
enum NodeType {OPERATOR, VARIABLE};
enum Operator {AND, OR, NOT, IFF, PLY};
struct Node {
    enum NodeType typ;
    enum Operator op;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
```

Parentheses don't appear explictly in the structure. Any `struct Node` instance with `typ == OPERATOR` effectively parenthesizes the two terms that `left` and `right` elements point to.  You would also have to decide on a convention for the NOT operator: only one of `left`, `right` point to the negated term.